# Disable Kafka Logs

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is it possible to disable logs in example after start project?

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = all
    batch.size = 16384
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
```

Comment: In general, it is useful to keep this output to verify properties are set correctly

Answer (score 1):

You just need to raise the logging level of `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig`. Something like `log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer=WARN` with log4j.

Other logging frameworks have similar configuration.

Comment: OK, but how do I do that?